# How to push spacebar action to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to check spacebar action

like this

example sentenc 
=> abcd efghi jhabcd   qwer

```
let emptyArray = []
```

if I write sentence
=> `emptyArray = ['abcd', 'space', 'efghi', 'space', 'space', 'space', 'qwer']`

how to make array?

Comment: you can put this condition where ever you need:  if(e.keyCode == 32)

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this

```
var r = 'abcd efghi jhabcd qwer'.replace(/ /g,' space ').split(' ');
console.log(r)
```

**Output :**

```
["abcd", "space", "efghi", "space", "jhabcd", "space", "qwer"]
```

Comment: Happy to Help :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
const a = "abcd efghi jhabcd qwer"

const arr = a.split(' ').join(' space ').split(' ')


console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.prototype.split(' '), which will break up your string into an array of strings separated by what is in the argument of the function [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).  You can then join then back together into a long string using .join(' space '), and then split that again using .split(' '), and you will get the exact result you asked for.  So all together:

```js
exampleSentence.split(' ').join(' space ').split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

To split it all into an array on spaces is easy:

```
let wordArray = [],
    str = 'abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yzAB';

wordArray = wordArray.concat( str.split( " " ) );
```

However, if you wanted to put the word space in-between each word in the array, you need to add an extra step:

```
let wordArray = [],
    str = 'abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yzAB';

str = str.replace(/\s/g, " space ");

wordArray = wordArray.concat( str.split( " " ) );
```

However, if your sentence is coming from a specific user input, that is a completely different set of code. I will update this answer if that is indeed the case (and if that is so, could you give me more information).

Comment: You are right.
I want to store the inputs as an array.
But if space is 2, it seems to be an error

Answer (score 0):

jquery event.which property returns which keyboard key or mouse button was pressed for the event. The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
        // your code
    }
});
```